# How do I solve linear equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, linear-equation

Basically, I need to solve the number of classes to be attended to reach a certain percentage. It leaves me with this formula:

`required_percentage=(attended+x/conducted+x)*100`.

Here, I require "x" as it is the number of classes to be attended.

I tried using `sympy` module:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x
sympy.solve(f"(({attended}+x)/({conducted}+x))*100/{required}","x")
```

But this just constantly gave this answer: `[-4]`.
Upon manual calculation it solves to `30`.

Comment: Don't you mean `- {required}`.  Sympy is trying to set that equation to 0.

Comment: It would also be useful if you let us know what values you used for `attended`, `conducted`, and `required`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x=((required_percentage * conducted)-(100*attended))/(100-required_percentage)

Got from just manually rearranging the equation for x.